# Book with reptilian creatures who live on by having their brains eaten

Tags: story-identification

I read a brief portion of a book where higher order reptilian creatures, in order to propagate themselves, allowed their brains to be eaten by a younger stronger reptile who's mind was then overtaken by the one eaten so the old reptile was "reborn" in the younger and stronger. The story followed a reptile "general" on the run. I'm hoping to find the book so I can finish it! Ring any bells with anyone?

Answer (score 8):

[*Kren of the Mitchegai*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leo_Frankowski#Other_books), by Leo Frankowski;  great read!

From [a review](http://heliologue.com/2010/06/08/kren-of-the-mitchegai-2/):

> When a teenager eats an adult’s brain, the motile brain cells travel through the bloodstream and supplant the existing brain cells, bringing the adult’s knowledge and memories with them. This is, in fact, how Kren managed to stay alive for many hundreds of years; as a good mine slave, his owners simply kept feeding him to teenagers when his old body wore out.

Kren himself is a former mine slave who eventually works his way up to Duke by virtue of (illegally) cannibalizing his fellow adults.